# Kubernetes - Monitoring networking latency/bandwidth between servers

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, heapster, prometheus-operator

I have a Kubernetes cluster running in the Google Cloud consisting of 4 servers. What is the **easiest** way to monitor networking latency/bandwidth **between the servers** ?

Is it possible to have a "scriptable" solution so I can repeat the deployment on different clusters in the future with minimal need for overhead ?

Thanks

PS - Kind of new at this so apologies if I didn't get the terms exact

Comment: I am specifically looking for **between** the servers in the cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at that post: http://paulbakker.io/docker/docker-cloud-network-performance/

They use a Docker Image on each host and test network performance between two machines. Maybe that's something you could do and even script ;)

Comment: Thanks. If I am on the Google Cloud do I need something additional besides the monitoring they provide like Heapster ?

Comment: I am not pretty sure. We are hosting Kubernetes ourself. I would recommend to just try there images and maybe have a look there image https://hub.docker.com/r/arjanschaaf/centos-qperf/ It's just a centos7 image with net-tools and qperf. So maybe it will work just like that